# Modules in Fortran OpenMP declared default shared

Tags: module, fortran, openmp, default, shared

I want to declare all the variables in a Fortran MODULE as SHARED in an OpenMP parallel region.  I can do this for COMMON blocks, e.g., SHARED(/commonname/).  Is there a way to do this for modules?

Comment: You can use `default(shared)` to make everything not specified otherwise shared, but that's the default anyway.

Comment: This may be what @el.mojito means, but just to be absolutely clear variables accessed via modules are by default shared.

Comment: I have chosen to declare the default on my loops as PRIVATE.  And this causes the module variables to be private as well -- I tested it.  What I'm looking for is some way to declare all the variables in a module as shared, in the same manner that all the variables in a COMMON block can be shared as I showed in the example.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I do not think that's possible. Could be wrong though.

Comment: I think you are correct, although I did find something useful.  I can declare variables in the module as THREADPRIVATE, so when I "use" the module, that declaration persists.  But if I need them shared, I have to declare them individually (unless someone can tell me different).